# Optimizing VBA Select Code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to reword the code below to avoid using the Select and Selection terms.  I tried to Range("S"...).Copy instead of .Select but that didn't work for some reason.  Does anyone know a way I can reword this to avoid Select and Selection statements and why my change .Select to .Copy wouldn't have worked?

The code below looks in Column A for the identifiers Tango and Alpha.  Then it uses those identifiers to figure out the range between rows to select in Column S and copies and pastes them as values.  I can confirm the code does run as is.

```
Sub copy_paste()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim FoundCell1 As Range
        Dim FoundCell2 As Range
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        Const WHAT_TO_FIND1 As String = "Tango"
        Set FoundCell1 = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND1)

        Const WHAT_TO_FIND2 As String = "Alpha"
        Set FoundCell2 = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND2)

        Range("S" & FoundCell1.Row + 1 & ":S" & FoundCell2.Row - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False

End sub
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! It's not clear whether the code you're presenting is working or not... and since code that doesn't work as intended isn't ready for a peer review and is therefore off-topic on this site, reviewers are more likely to vote to close and move on - please [edit] your post to clarify, and note that you'll get much better/thorough feedback if you include the whole procedure, rather than just a snippet taken out of its context. I really hope you edit & clarify - there's a lot of enhancement opportunities (and hidden bugs) in there!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Hi Mathieu, thank you for your feedback.  I've edited the post the clarify what the code does and can confirm that it does run.

Comment: Why are you doing the `.PasteSpecial`? Are `Tango` and `Alpha` (or the rows between them) the result of formulas and you're trying to overwrite the formulas with the actual values?

Comment: @FreeMan The .PasteSpecial is just from me recording my macro and that's what it spit out.  Tango and Alpha are the unique identifiers that are located on the row numbers I want to pull.  The rows can shift so that's why I have those there so that it can dynamically determine between which rows to perform on.

Comment: Named ranges can be your friend. Your code will then become `<Qualified>.Range("MyNamedRange").Value = <Qualified>.Range("MyNamedRange").Value`

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TinMan: Please post answers as answers and not as comments. Especially not as links to some external document in the comments.

Comment: @JDoe the macro recorder would not have spit out a `.PasteSpecial` unless that's what you did when you recorded it. If you don't need to `Paste Values`, but can accept formulas in your destination, that can significantly change the code (and the results).

Answer (score 1):

To start with:  You are currently not using the `wb` Workbook object after setting it.  Is it needed in other code, or can it be removed?

If you are just trying to 'flatten' the range to get rid of any formula, you can just use `<Range>.Value = <Range>.Value`, instead of Copy / PasteSpecial

```vb
Range("S" & FoundCell1.Row + 1 & ":S" & FoundCell2.Row - 1).Select
'Selection.Copy
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
```

You can also use a [`With` Statment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) to replace the requirement for a Select or Selection.

```vb
'Range("S" & FoundCell1.Row + 1 & ":S" & FoundCell2.Row - 1).Select
With w.Range("S" & FoundCell1.Row + 1 & ":S" & FoundCell2.Row - 1)
    .Value = .Value
End With
'Selection.Copy
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
```

And, this is personal preference, but you *could* use `.Offset`, `.EntireRow` and `.Column` to define the range instead of building a text string address:

```vb
With ws.Range(FoundCell1.Offset(1, 0), FoundCell2.Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.Columns("S")
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

(This only requires "Column S" to be defined once, in case you need to change it later - the other option would be to have it in a `Const` at the start of the Sub)

As yet-another-alternative, you could use `WorksheetFunction.Match` to retrieve the Rows directly (`TangoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(WHAT_TO_FIND1, ws.Columns("A"), 0)` would give the same result as `FoundCell1.Row`)